# How to do an action when tab bar item is pressed every time Swift

Tags: ios

I am making an application with TabBar. In the Tab Bar there are 2 tabs. One of those tabs is history which is linked with a table view which shows history. I want to refresh that view every time when i click that so that i can get updated tableview. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to put the reload call in the `viewWillAppear` of the `viewController` with the table you want to reload, then, every time it is presented it will reload the data.

Anyway, if you want to catch the tap on of the tabs, you need to subclass `UITabBarController` and then implement this method `-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item`

Comment: already select the bar item reload data but next time click the bar item how to fire the tableview reload the data

Comment: @sureshswaminathan -- it means again you touch  the same tap , you want to perform reload correct or not

Comment: @sureshswaminathan every time you tap the bar item the method I wrote will get called, so you can use it to reload the data.

Answer (score 0):

Hi easiest solution for swift 4, to reload view by tapping again on tab bar icon.

```
 @objc 
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
                 didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0  {
       viewController.viewDidLoad()
    }
 }
```